# UCAExc:::3.0.7 user lacks privilege or object not found: SLIPSET

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have looked through similar threads on this site and none of the suggested answers seem to work. I am writing a java program that interacts with an Access database using SQL. I have successfully connected to the database and pulled information from it. However, I need to update the database and I keep running into this error

> UCAExc:::3.0.7 user lacks privilege or object not found: SLIPSET

Why am I not able to successfully update the Access database?

Here is the code relevant to the updates

```
String sqlSlip ="UPDATE Slip" +
                "SET slipOpen = 0 AND boatID =?" +
                "WHERE slipNumber = ?";

PreparedStatement slipUpdate = connection.prepareStatement(sqlSlip);
slipUpdate.setDouble(1, boatIDdub);
slipUpdate.setDouble(2, rs.getInt("slipNumber"));

ResultSet updateSlip = slipUpdate.executeQuery();

String sqlCustomer = " INSERT INTO Customer(customerLName, customerFName, slipNumber, boatID, customerNumber)" +
                     "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement custUpdate = connection.prepareStatement(sqlCustomer);
custUpdate.setString(1,custLName);
custUpdate.setString(2, custFName);
custUpdate.setDouble(3, rs.getInt("slipNumber"));
custUpdate.setDouble(4, boatIDdub);
custUpdate.setDouble(5, customerNumber);

ResultSet updateCust = custUpdate.executeQuery();
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were to inspect the contents of your `sqlSlip` string you would see that it contains

```sql
UPDATE SlipSET slipOpen = 0 AND boatID =?WHERE slipNumber = ?
```

You need to add a space to the end of each string fragment and use a comma instead of `AND` ...

```java
String sqlSlip ="UPDATE Slip " +
                "SET slipOpen = 0, boatID = ? " +
                "WHERE slipNumber = ?";
```

... so that the string contains

```sql
UPDATE Slip SET slipOpen = 0, boatID = ? WHERE slipNumber = ?
```

Also note that to perform an INSERT query you need to use `.executeUpdate()`, not `.executeQuery()`.